# Cosmos bulk insertion does not return success. Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; Reason: ();

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, bad-request

I have partition key as ServiceId which is matching in my container. but I am still getting this error. here is the object I am trying to upsert and code to do upsert.

### Error:
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 413484d3-0d39-4b0f-92ac-6ffdc2fa0ffb; Reason: ();

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.d__39`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
here is my code snippet.

````
 public class SubscriptionLookup 
    {
        #region public constructors
        public SubscriptionLookup()
        {
            TimeToLive = null;
            SubscriptionId = Guid.Empty.ToString(); 
            ServiceId = Guid.Empty.ToString();
            ParentServiceId = Guid.Empty.ToString();
            Source = string.Empty;
          //  PropertyBag = string.Empty;
        }
        #endregion public constructors

        #region public properties
        [DataMember]
        public string ServiceId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
       // [DataMember]
       // public string PropertyBag { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ParentServiceId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Source { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public XDocument AssociatedDocument { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ttl", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int? TimeToLive { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string PartitionKey
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceId;
            }
        }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return SubscriptionId;
            }
        }

public async Task BulkUpsert(List<SubscriptionLookup> items)
        {
            const string methodName = "BulkUpsert";
            try
            {
                var concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    concurrentTasks.Add(container.UpsertItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.PartitionKey)));
                }

               await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"[{ClassName}] [{methodName}]: Encounter error while doing bulk insert for Subscription {ex}");

            }
        }```
````

Comment: are you using gateway or direct mode? also why you are inserting items one by one? have you enabled bulkmode?

Comment: Try disabling Bulk, you will get the full error message